# supervisor or cat or bash doesn't see changed file

Tags: bash, caching, supervisord

I have a supervisor 'program' (`queue.sh`) that runs a bash script that reads from a text file and runs another program if the text file is not empty:

```
while true; do

        # Read line 1
        line=$(head -n1 ./.queue)
        echo $line

        if [ "$line" != "" ]; then
                # Remove line 1
                sed -i '1d' ./.queue

                # Call the download script
                /usr/bin/env php download.php $line
        else
                echo "Queue empty"
        fi

        sleep 2

done
```

`download.php` takes a few minutes, and then the next line is ran. If `.queue` contains 20 lines, `queue.sh` will be busy a long time. When it's not busy, it checks `.queue` for content every 2 sec.

My queue file currently has 3 lines. When I run `queue.sh` manually, I can see it working: it finds line 1, chops it off, and runs `download.php`. Supervisor doesn't! Even after restarting the job and the entire daemon, it just keeps saying `Queue empty` every 2 sec. After changing the message, and restarting the job, it now keeps saying `Queue empty II` every 2 sec. But `.queue` is not empty, so it should run the lines.

Is there some kind of super persistent file cache in the supervisor context? I've restarted the job and the daemon. I've run `free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free` (not inside supervisor context!). I've `touch .queue`. Nothing works. Why does supervisor's `queue.sh` insist `.queue` is empty?

Comment: Are you sure the script is running in the correct directory? Try changing `./.queue` to an absolute pathname.

Comment: Or put a `cd` command earlier in the script to switch to the directory that contains `.queue`. BTW, there's no need for `./`, that's the default for all relative pathnames.

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Supervisor has a `directory` config which fixes everything. And apparently restarting the program isn't enough. I had to restart the entire supervisor service after every change to the program conf file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the directory. Supervisor runs in `/` by default, not where the program executable happens to be. Supervisor has a [`directory` config](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) which fixed it. New config file:

```
[program:xx]
command=/bin/bash queue.sh
directory=/my/path/xx
```

And I had to restart the service (`service supervisor restart`), not just the program (`supervisorctl restart xx`).